# Close an Adobe Acrobat file opened by another user on different computer (same network)

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working on a process to automate a report for my work.  One of the final bits that i would like to work on is understanding if it is possible to close a pdf file that is opened by another user at a different computer (albeit on the same network).  I have used tutorials and written the following macro and function to successfully test if the file is open, however, I now want to know if it is possible to actually close the file from a different and remote location.

Does anyone have any advice for how to do this, or if it is possible.  I have seen similar items for close excel documents, but not the pdf documents.

```
'function to determine if file is open
Function IsFileOpen(FileName As String)

Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

On Error Resume Next
ff = FreeFile()
Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
Close ff
ErrNo = Err
On Error GoTo 0

'select case depending on if file is open or not
Select Case ErrNo
Case 0:    IsFileOpen = False
Case 70:   IsFileOpen = True
Case Else: Error ErrNo

End Select

End Function



'method to close DOR in pdf form if it is already open
Sub closeAcrobat()

Dim sStatus

sStatus = IsFileOpen("M:\Daily_Outage_Report\Active\Operations_Daily_Outage_Report_" _
& Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".pdf")

If sStatus = True Then
    MsgBox "file is open"
Else
    MsgBox "file is not open"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know whether it is possible or not, but I'm certainly **hoping** that it isn't.  I'd hate to be using a file and then have some other user close it on me.

Comment: Yes it is possible if you have Admin Access

Comment: @SiddharthRout assuming I had admin access, what would be the best way to execute it.

Comment: I am still deciding whether it is ethical to share it or not :D because like @YowE3K is concerned, I would be damn pissed if someone closes the file I am working on...

Comment: I will let the community decide. If majority says, post it, I will...

Comment: @SiddharthRout Hm, to give some context, I work in a room with monitors all over the walls.  We keep the report up on a screen from the day before, and in an effort to not have to get up and walk across a room to close it every day, I want to be able to remotely close it.  Small price to pay in walking, but if I can get around it, that would be nice.  I can assure the audience that nobody well ever be working with the pdf document.

Comment: I have posted a question in [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330572/unsure-if-i-should-post-an-answer) Please gimme some time

Comment: @Rivers31334: The better approach is to have an application on the target computer that automatically opens the correct document each day.

Comment: @RobertHarvey This is actually a great work around and solution.  I saw your comment on the Meta, but what you are saying here works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible if you have `Admin Rights (Phew!)`.

To manually test it

1. Click Windows Start | Run | Cmd.exe
2. Type `OpenFiles` at command prompt and press the Enter key
3. You will see the list of files/folders that are opened. They will be listed as `ID`, `Accessed By`, `Type` , `Open File (Path\executable)`
4. To disconnect you can use File ID, UserName, or file name Like `OpenFiles /Disconnect /ID 123`

Now all this can be done from VBA if you know how to issue DOS commands from VBA.

Comment: I think Robert Harvey has a great work around.  Apologies that I just saw this as you posted this solution.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: (a) Will that actually work on a different computer, or do you have to remote in to the computer that the file is open on, or at least be logged on to the computer (file server) on which the file is located?  (b) does it actually close the file, or does it just disconnect the connection between the file server (for example) and the user's computer, thus leaving the user reading the document from the memory cache?

Comment: `1` No you do not need to remote in `2` It closes the file

Comment: Seems strange that even an admin user on computer A can see files that are located on server S which are open by a user on computer B with just a simple command.  I would have thought that they would need to either specify the file that they are interested in, or the server that the file is located on, or the computer that is accessing the file.

Comment: Ahh - I see you mentioned that they could do the disconnect with just the filename

Comment: Can you not remotely log off the machine? As an administrator, it will be much easier? Lot of Admins do that when users forget to logoff/switch off the pcs before going home...

Comment: Anyways it is 3:17AM on this part of the planet. I am off to bed Gnite :)